# Sort Order Dropdown in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, webforms

I have a Gridview control with two columns: One is ID (a label) and the other is Sort Order (dropdown list). The dropdown is numbered from 1 to *n*, where *n* is the number of rows in the Gridview.

For example:

```
ID        Sort Order
001          1
002          2
003          3
004          4
```

After I change the value in the dropdown list for one of the rows - for example, I'll change the Sort Order dropdown for ID `002` from `2` to `3` - the gridview should be updated like this:

```
 ID        Sort Order
001          1
003          2
002          3
004          4
```

I need the logic to accomplish this within the `SelectedIndexChanged` event for the dropdown, as well as the code to perform the update to the database.

Comment: the sort order still remains 1 2 3 4 ??

Comment: @codebrain, you'll notice the `ID` 002 has no longer got a `Sort Order` of 2 it's now 3

Comment: Can you give us more information? How is the data bound to the GridView, and what does the model look like?

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understood your problem then find solution of your problem as below :

**Code Behind**

> ```
>    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
>    {
>      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>      {
>         if (!Page.IsPostBack)
>         {
>             BindGrid();
>         }
>     }
>
>     protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
>         {
>             DropDownList objDropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
>             objDropDownList.DataSource = CustomSorting.GetAll();
>             objDropDownList.DataTextField = "SOText";
>             objDropDownList.DataValueField = "SOID";
>             objDropDownList.DataBind();
>
>             HiddenField objHiddenField = e.Row.FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;
>             string currSortOrder = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objHiddenField.Value) ? objHiddenField.Value :
>      "0");
>             objDropDownList.SelectedIndex = objDropDownList.Items.IndexOf(objDropDownList.Items.FindByValue(currSortOrder));
>         }
>     }
>
>     protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         DropDownList objDropDownList = sender as DropDownList;
>         string test = objDropDownList.SelectedValue;
>
>         GridViewRow currRow = objDropDownList.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
>         Label objLabel = currRow.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
>         HiddenField objHiddenField = currRow.FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;
>
>         List<TestClass> lstTestClass = PageData;
>         if (lstTestClass.Exists(x => x.SortOrder == Convert.ToInt32(test)))
>             lstTestClass.Find(x => x.SortOrder == Convert.ToInt32(test)).SortOrder =
>      Convert.ToInt32(objHiddenField.Value);
>         if (lstTestClass.Exists(x => x.ID == objLabel.Text))
>             lstTestClass.Find(x => x.ID == objLabel.Text).SortOrder = Convert.ToInt32(test);
>         PageData = lstTestClass;
>         BindGrid();
>     }
>
>     protected List<TestClass> PageData
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             return (Session["_PageData"] == null) ? TestClass.GetAll() : Session["_PageData"] as List<TestClass>;
>         }
>         set
>         {
>             Session["_PageData"] = value;
>         }
>     }
>     protected void BindGrid()
>     {
>         GridView1.DataSource = PageData.OrderBy(x=>x.SortOrder);
>         GridView1.DataBind();
>     }
> }
>
> public class CustomSorting
> {
>     public int SOID { get; set; }
>     public string SOText { get; set; }
>
>     public static List<CustomSorting> GetAll()
>     {
>         return new List<CustomSorting>(){
>            new CustomSorting(){SOID=1,SOText="1"},
>            new CustomSorting(){SOID=2,SOText="2"},
>            new CustomSorting(){SOID=3,SOText="3"},
>            new CustomSorting(){SOID=4,SOText="4"},
>        };
>     }
> }
>
> public class TestClass
> {
>     public string ID { get; set; }
>     public int SortOrder { get; set; }
>
>    public static List<TestClass> GetAll()
>     {
>         return new List<TestClass>(){
>            new TestClass(){ID="001",SortOrder=1},
>            new TestClass(){ID="002",SortOrder=2},
>            new TestClass(){ID="003",SortOrder=3},
>            new TestClass(){ID="004",SortOrder=4}
>        }.OrderBy(x=>x.SortOrder).ToList();
>     }
> }
> ```

**ASPX changes:**

> ```
>  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
>  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
>     <Columns>
>         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
>             </ItemTemplate>
>         </asp:TemplateField>
>         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sort Order">
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"      Value='<%#Eval("SortOrder") %>' />
>                 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
>  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
>             </ItemTemplate>
>         </asp:TemplateField>
>     </Columns>
> </asp:GridView>
> ```